# fetch="join" does not select <version> column of table

Tags: hibernate

I have a table that has a  column
and has a

```
<many-to-one name="request" class="foo.bar" column="REQUEST_ID" fetch="join"/>
```

When the select happens, it fetches the request object, but is unable to fetch the version property. it is set to null

works if i set fetch="select", but then there is a hit on performance.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, according to the hibernate documentation, fetch=join will use otter join and get all related fields, including the version field. It means that when you do a select hql, similar fields like version will be null.

This [link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching) is a clue for my opinion.

Comment: I dont qute understand. why would similar fields like version be null? Will the join query not fetch the values for it?